# C++ file io multiple lines

Tags: c++

I am trying to read from a .txt file one line at a time. i want to take a string and a double value from each line. Each line has a name and a salary, separated by a comma e.g.

> John Doyle, 30000
>
> Ian Smith, 32000
>
> etc.

I will then change these values and re-enter the new values into a new .txt file e.g.

> John Doyle, 1100, 31000, 2300
>
> Ian Smite, 1300, 32000, 3000

I am really not sure if i am going the right way about it or not. My current code:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string name;
double data;

ifstream infile;
infile.open("worker.txt");

ofstream outfile;
outfile.open("worker2.txt");

infile >> name >> data;

while (!infile.fail())
{
    //do something with the name and salary read in
    double backPay = data * 7.6 / 100 / 2;
    double newAnnual = data * 7.6 / 100 + data;
    double newMonthly = data * 7.6 / 100 + data;
    double monthly = newMonthly / 12;

    // write inputted data into the file.
    outfile << backPay << ", " << newAnnual << ", " << monthly << ", " << 
endl;

    // then try another read
    infile >> name >> data;
}
outfile.close();
infile.close();
}
```

Comment: Well, when you run this code, does it do what you want it to?  If it doesn't, have you stepped through the code with a debugger to see where it falls apart?

Comment: currently, it does not print anything into workers2.txt and I am not sure why

Comment: `infile >> name` will stop scanning on space. So "John Doyle" will just be read as "John". [`std::getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) can help.

Comment: Are you sure opening infile worked?

Comment: wil std::getline() give me one line as a string? or can i take the name and salary into separate variables from each line?

Comment: `getline()` can take a 3rd parameter for a delimiter. For example: `std::getline(infile, name, ',');`

Comment: Thanks guys. I will try using getline() and see how I get on

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the working version of your requirements.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string name;
string tempData; //since getline function only accepts string params, you need this
double data;

ifstream infile;
infile.open("worker.txt");

ofstream outfile;
outfile.open("worker2.txt");

while (getline(infile, name, ',')) //firstly get the name as Johnny suggested
{
    getline(infile, tempData); // while on the same line, we can read the salary of that person
    data = atof(tempData.c_str()); //now convert the gotten string value into a double for calculations
    double backPay = data * 7.6 / 100 / 2;
    double newAnnual = data * 7.6 / 100 + data;
    double newMonthly = data * 7.6 / 100 + data;
    double monthly = newMonthly / 12;

    // write inputted data into the file.
    outfile << name << ", " << backPay << ", " << newAnnual << ", " << monthly << endl; //write the name and values as required into the output file  

}
outfile.close();
infile.close();
}
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation, of what is wrong in the question.

Comment: Hello Craig, I compiled, ran and tested the code using g++ compiler. If you have minGW installed on your machine, then you can just copy the above code and run it through the command prompt using command "g++ -o test test.cpp" and then "test.exe". Alternatively, in your case, you can try to get rid of "using namespace std;" and put "std" namespace in front of the datatypes which visual studio is complaining about (i.e. std::string, std::getline...etc).